# Looping through XML file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have a XML file below ..I want to loop through this file and extract the node node value like for node com get the name value and then loop 2 times to get the file values.

```
<common>
  <com name="Test1.css">
    <file name="Tech.css">
    <file name="Comp.css"> 
  </com>
  <com name="Test2.css">
    <file name="HR.css">
    <file name="HR2.css"> 
  </com> 
</common>
```

I started using the below VBScript to start looping but I am getting an error Object required:Root
Can someone please have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong here

Option Explicit

```
Dim Root

Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
objXMLDoc.async = False 
objXMLDoc.load("C:\test\combineXML.xml")    
Set Root = objXMLDoc.documentElement 
WScript.Echo Root
Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagName("common")     
For Each Elem In NodeList 
WScript.Echo Elem.text

Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error `Object required:Root` indicates that there was a parsing error during `objXMLDoc.load()` (because that's the only situation where `documentElement` would be set to `Nothing`).

Check `objXMLDoc.parseError`.

In fact you must always check if there were parse errors after loading an XML document.

On a more general note you should never use object references like `documentElement` without checking that they are valid. That's bad style.

---

Hint: The *root node* and the *document element* are two different things.

- The root node is `/` (essentially, the root node is the document)
- The document element in your case is `<common>`
- This means: `objXMLDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("common")` will be empty

Comment: I checked for objXMLDoc.parseError and I am getting a this number -1072896659  ...not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: It means your XML document is not well-formed. There is an error description in the parse error, read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756041(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Yep my mistake..Thanks for ur help guys..forgot closing the child elements.